# React - How to use a hook in a button onClick

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I have a component which looks like the following. When the button is clicked I want my GraphQL modification to run. However with what I have so far I keep seeing the error: `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`.

I could place that code out the function, however I don't want it run as soon as the button is loaded, only when the button itself is clicked.

Any help appreciated.

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useMutation } from 'react-apollo';

export default function SubscriptionButton(props) {

    function useUpdateSubscription() {
        const [onDeleteHandler, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(SUBSCRIPTION_MODIFY)

        if (data) {
            window.location.replace(data.appSubscriptionCreate.confirmationUrl)
        }
    }

    return (
        <Button primary onClick={() => useUpdateSubscription()}>
            Select
        </Button>
    )
}
```

Comment: Did you check https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/ ? Why are you using useMutation inside your function, as the error says, hooks must be inside the body of a function component. Can't you take it to the top of your function component (outside of useUpdateSubscription

Comment: Good point - I should have read that. So it says it does not automatically execute the mutation https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#calling-the-mutate-function Which means I can place it outside and follow the rules of hooks. Issue resolved :) Thanks.